# Jackson serialize nested attribute with same name

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

Currently, I have a JSON response of the following type.

```
{
   "user":{
      "user":{
         "name":"Demo",
         "age":25,
         "eail":"demo@abc.com"
      },
      "address":{
         "country":"NZ"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to map my custom class to nested user attributes.

```
@Data
public class Demo{
      @JsonProperty("user")
      private User user;
      private Address address;
}
```

But when I am trying to get the attribute, it is always sending `null` value. I think it is maping to first occurance of `"user"` in line no 2.

How can I map it to correct `user` attribute in line no 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mapping starts from the root of JSON so the correct class definition for this JSON will be this

```java
public class Demo {
    @JsonProperty("user")
    private DemoUser user;
}
```

```java
public class DemoUser {
    @JsonProperty("user")
    private User user;

    @JsonProperty("address")
    private Address address;
}
```

If you want to keep the class as it is and only want to use the inner 'user', you can do it using JsonNode like this

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readValue(jsonString, JsonNode.class);
Demo demo = mapper.readValue(node.at("/user").toString(), Demo.class);
```

The at() method accepts the JSON path expression which is the path to a particular node in the JSON.

Here, `"/user"` means it will find the node `user` from the root of JSON and will return it.

Similarly,

```
node.at("/user/user").toString();
```

will give you

```
{
  "name":"Demo",
  "age":25,
  "eail":"demo@abc.com"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Prateek for the detailed answer.